# Why do we daemonize processes?

Tags: daemon, rc

I've read and understood about how you create a daemon process, but from everything I read I never really understood **why** it needs to be done.

I've read that we do the fork - setsid - fork to avoid the process to gain control of a terminal, but what does this mean ?
If I start a program in the background using & (for example './script &' ), what makes this process' execution different than if I ran normally a program that turns itself into a daemon ?

Does this simply mean that if I logout the background process will stop and the daemon will keep running ? I'm really having trouble understanding the 'gain control of a terminal' thing.

The reason this bothers me is because I'm working on an embedded RPi on a robot and I thus need to make programs start on boot.
Currently I'm just starting them from rc.local with a command like this `su user -c 'python /home/user/launcher.py &' &`.
I've never had any problem with the program starting on boot (I can even see the process using `ps -e` when SSHing to the RPi), but I would like to know if there's any risk / if it's bad practice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's more than one question, each could have long answers.  Briefly

- *If I start a program in the background using & (for example './script &' ), what makes this process' execution different than if I ran normally a program that turns itself into a daemon ?*

  Running a program in the background, it no longer is directly controlled by the terminal (you can't simply `^C` it), but it can still write to the terminal and interfere with your work.  Typically a daemon will separate itself from the terminal (in addition to forking) and its output/error would be redirected to files.
- *Does this simply mean that if I logout the background process will stop and the daemon will keep running ?*

  The background process could be protected with `nohup` but unless its output were redirected, closing the terminal would prevent it from writing, producing an error that likely would stop it.
- *I would like to know if there's any risk / if it's bad practice.*

  Besides the problem of keeping track of the program's output (and error messages), there's the problem of restarting it if it happens to die.  A service script fits into the way the other services on the system are designed, providing a more/less standard way of controlling the daemon.

Comment: Thanks ! That was clear. Now I realize I don't really understand how rc.local works as I'm able to start programs from it and they work well although they have an output. Are rc.locals stderr/stdout fds redirected to /dev/null by default ?

Comment: That will probably come out on the system console, e.g., `/dev/tty1` (some systems differ).